# Add and remove object from array when the observable created from knockout.mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

The following is a very simplified version of my code..

My html code:

```
<div class="container body-content" data-bind="foreach:base">
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="with:s">
        <div class="col-md-4"><pre data-bind="text:sp"></pre></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: spd">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:value, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.addval">add</button><button data-bind="click: $parent.removeval">rem</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
<script src="knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
            <script src="knockout.mapping.js"></script>
            <script>
                var data = [{
                    "s": {
                        "sp": "abc",
                        "spd": [
                          {
                              "value": ""
                          }
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "xyz",
                 }];
                var AppScope = function () {

                    function BaseViewModel() {
                        var self = this;
                        self.base = ko.observableArray();
                        self.base(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
                    }
                    ko.applyBindings(new BaseViewModel());
                }();
            </script>
```

The 'data' array comes from server and has a much complex data structure, so $root can not be used.
The style used [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) may be the answer but not able to figure it out yet..

The code works except for the buttons. I would like to understand how to add {value:""} object to the array under 'spd' and remove the same on press of addval and remval functions.

All help is sincerely appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a weird setup, but I'm just going with what you provided. The `spd` initially has one member with an empty value. The input box allows you to change the value. The `add` button duplicates the value into a new entry. The `remove` button removes the current entry.

The trickiest bit is figuring out the structure from `self.base` down to the `spd` observableArray. Update: I've modified the click binding handlers to take the `s` context (which is `$parent`) so they know which `s`'s `spd` they're working with.

I changed the context from `$parent` to `$root` because it didn't make sense to me to create `addval` and `removeval` functions at the `s` level.

```js
var data = [{
  "s": {
    "sp": "abc",
    "spd": [{
      "value": ""
    }]
  },
  "type": "xyz",
}];
var AppScope = function() {

  function BaseViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.base = ko.observableArray();
    self.base(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
    self.addval = function(sData, data) {
      sData.spd.push({value: ko.observable(data.value())});
    };
    self.removeval = function(sData, data) {
      sData.spd.remove(data);
    }

  }
  ko.applyBindings(new BaseViewModel());
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<div class="container body-content" data-bind="foreach:base">
  <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="with:s">
    <div class="col-md-4"><pre data-bind="text:sp"></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: spd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:value, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
        <button data-bind="click: (data) => $root.addval($parent, data)">add</button>
        <button data-bind="click: (data) => $root.removeval($parent, data)">rem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you wanted to do the same sort of thing using unobtrusive event handling (and you have jQuery), the relevant code might look like this:

```
function BaseViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.base = ko.observableArray();
    self.base(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
  }
  ko.applyBindings(new BaseViewModel());

  $('body').on('click', '.add-btn', function() {
    const context = ko.contextFor(this);
    const data = ko.dataFor(this);
    const s = context.$parent;

    s.spd.push({
      value: ko.observable(data.value())
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
    const context = ko.contextFor(this);
    const data = ko.dataFor(this);
    const s = context.$parent;

    s.spd.remove(data);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but will not work.. My data array has multiple objects, I have just provided one here to show the data structure. Also the actual object coming from server has a far complex data structure, so can not use $root. Something like http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html will have to be used but unfortunately unable to figure out..

Comment: How about now? The click handlers pass `$parent` (which is `s`, coming from the `with` binding) and the data item to `addval` and `removeval`.